# Websphere MQ - Java connection

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Our websphere MQ GUI shows the java client to be connected .

Further on investigation, we see Java application on the client machine is not even on but developed an error and quit.

Question is when the Jave program terminates should the MQ - Java connection not automatically disconnect ?

Expert advise needed .

Comment: Can you refresh the MQ GUI?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the application is still connected?  You say client machine, so is the SVRCONN channel used by the java application still running?  Did you refresh the WMQ Explorer GUI (as Shashi asked?).
MQ does clean up the connections but it depends on the underlying operating system which should clear/mark the port as unused (In linux, net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time)